# Using pyautogui to unlock screen

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pyautogui

I'm using `pyautogui` to unlock my computer screen on Windows 10. Here's the script:

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
time.sleep(7)
print("Pressing 'space'")
pyautogui.press('space')
print("Waiting for 3 seconds.")
time.sleep(3)
print("Typying Password")
pyautogui.press('p')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('a')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('s')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('s')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('w')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('o')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('r')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('d)
print("Hitting 'enter'")
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(9)
```

The script does simulate the spacebar as my lock screen is shifted to the screen where it asks for the password but it doesn't type in my password. I wonder why? When I manually open my account, the output of the script confirms that it ran successfully. What could be the cause of it?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Windows specifically prevents automated scripts from running while the computer is locked as a security precaution, so you won't be able to send any keyboard presses to the login screen.

Something similar also applies to, for example, AV software that prevents simulated mouse clicks or keyboard presses to its windows. This prevents malware from disabling the AV software.