# Unlock windows using python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to unlock the windows on a pre defined time in order to run a script using mouse and keyboard (pyautogui).
I am getting an error on the event of pyautogui.click(), at password screen (cx_Freeze error).

Can anybody support me on it?

See my code below and the error msg:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time



x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day, hour=10, minute=3, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

print(f'Script scheduled to run on: {y}')

secs=delta_t.seconds+1


def hello_world():
    try:
        pyautogui.click(1025,513, 2) # click to show the password box
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.typewrite("Asdfghjkl;'",2) # Type the password
        pyautogui.press('enter') # enter to login.
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass

    subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\z142192\Desktop\Programs_Created\StockOverviewScript\UpdateStockOverview.exe']) # Run this script after login.


t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False` to your code.

Comment: When programming it might be worth it to actually read pop ups and error messages. The pop-up literally tells you what to do...

Comment: Except that might not be the answer here. I wouldn't bet on PyAutoGUI being able to read or write the Windows lock screen.

Comment: @rassar, it  tried already with FAILSAFE = False but it is not working. It seems the python code stops after the click event (when the password box shows up).

Comment: @Kraay89, see the answer above to rassar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pyautogui to unlock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176112/using-pyautogui-to-unlock-screen)

Comment: @Kraay89, you right, it might be duplicated but still no solution. It should not be a big issue to unlock the windows once I have the password, right?!

Comment: But that's exactly what the answer on the question says. That it is impossible. At least through pyautogui, an perhaps by extension through scripts in general.